# Sql query to sum total area by converting it in a common base unit

Tags: sql

I want to create a stored procedure in which i want to sum totalarea (column name) from a table but have to check its unit from unit table(other table) and if the unit is not base unit then it should be convert to base unit first and then sum should be calculated. the unit Table is

[image]

Thnx in Advance

Comment: And where are your table with totalarea column?

Comment: What is base_unit supposed to mean? Why is it 2.5 for BGH and 1 for everything else?

Comment: the total area column is from different table and unit table means i ft=107639 hectare whereas 2.5 bgh=1 hecatre

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is join to the units table.  However, because there may not be matches, use a left outer join and then check for NULL values using the `coalesce()` function.  I think it should be something like:

```
select sum(t.area) * coalesce(u.Converting_unit, 1.0)/coalesce(u.Base_unit, 1.0) as TotalArea
from t left outer join
     units u
     on t.unit_code = u.unit_code
```

To be honest, I am a bit wary of this approach because it requires consistency in the converted-to units.  Something like:

```
select sum(t.area) * coalesce(u.Converting_unit, 1.0)/coalesce(u.Base_unit, 1.0) as TotalArea,
       u.base_unitcode
from t left outer join
     units u
     on t.unit_code = u.unit_code
group by u.base_unitcode
```

Seems safer.

I also don't understand how you convert from linear measures such as feet and meters to area measures such as hectares.  This suggests a problem with your choice of units.